One logistic regression model w/ multiple predictors or multiple models with one predictor each?
I imagine this is a sloppy solution to my problem and perhaps even completely invalid, but I'm trying fit a logistic regression model where I have some empty values (NA as I'm doing this in R). The empty values are because of incomplete data collection, so I'm pretty hesitant about any sort of imputing method as this would (I think) be akin to falsifying my data in my case. I'm left with removing observations that have empty values, but this could mean removing very many observations that are good for one predictor just because they're missing a value in another predictor.
As an extremely simplified example, say I have the follow dataset:
data <- data.frame(
  "Gender" = c("Man", "Woman", "Woman", NA, "Woman"),
  "Race" = c("White", "Black", NA, "Black", "White"),
  "State" = c("Sad", "Happy", "Sad", "Happy", "Sad")
)

If I wanted to see if Gender and Race can predict State, my first thought is to make a model that looks something like:
State ~ Gender + Race

However, if I deal with the NAs by deleting those observations, I'm removing one valid data point from Gender and one valid data point from Race, leaving me with 3 observations.
If I instead decided to make two separate models, I might have something like:
State ~ Gender
State ~ Race

Now if I delete the NA observations, I still have 4 observations for Gender and 4 for Race rather than 3 for each. But is this statistically a stupid thing to do? What am I losing by splitting this into two separate models? Is whatever I'm losing a bigger deal than the gained observations are worth?

What are you planning on doing with that model?

Say I give you two features: one is the sign of the number I'm thinking of, and the second one is the magnitude (the abs value)... can you build a model using only one of the two to guess the number I have in my mind? Not really... also, give a look a the simpson paradox, that's another case where independent models won't quite work

One possibility is to run an ordinal logistic regression with categorical predictors where the comparison group for each of your independent variables is the non-responding group.
